# Menu Navigation Drawer com ExpandableListView

Tags: android

Estou procurando como montar um menu padrão NavigationDrawer com ExpandableListView, mas só encontro exemplo e explicações de como montar com ListView, gostaria de alguma dica, tutorial ou exemplo para que eu consiga implementar.

[image]

Ou Algo como o dessa Imagem

[image]

Comment: [Sample App for android Navigation Drawer with expandablelistview](https://github.com/PrashamTrivedi/DrawerLayoutTest).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para implementar um navigation drawer com  expandadle list view, você vai precisar basicamente de duas classes:

**1- NavigationDrawer**: activity principal que conterá o navigation drawer.

**2 - AdapterDrawerItem**: adapter para modificar o layout padrão do navigation drawer

Primeiramente, vamos criar o adapter do navigation drawer:

**AdapterDrawerItem.java**

```
public class AdapterDrawerItem extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

// Opções que vão compor os itens pai e filho do expandable list
String[] listaPai = {"A","B","C","D"};
String[][] listaFilho ={{"A1","A2"},{"B1"},{"C1","C2","C3"},{"D1"}};
Context context;

public AdapterDrawerItem(Context context) {

    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return listaPai.length;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return listaFilho[groupPosition].length;
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {

    return listaPai[groupPosition];
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {

    return listaFilho[groupPosition][childPosition];
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        // Crie um layout com um textview para o item que corresponde ao pai
        convertView =  layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_drawer_item_pai,parent,false);
    }

    TextView pai = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_drawer_item_pai);
    pai.setText(listaPai[groupPosition]);
    convertView.setTag(listaPai[groupPosition]);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            // Crie um layout com um textview para o item que corresponde ao filho
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_drawer_item_filho,parent,false);
        }

        TextView filho = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_drawer_item_filho);
        filho.setText(listaFilho[groupPosition][childPosition]);
        convertView.setTag(listaFilho[groupPosition][childPosition]);

        return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}
```

}

Agora use o seguinte layout para o navigation drawer

**navigation_drawer_layout.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>     

<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#ffff"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Agora é só implementar a classe NavigationDrawer

**NavigationDrawer.java**

```
private AdapterDrawerItem adapterCustomDrawer;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation_drawer);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    adapterCustomDrawer = new AdapterDrawerItem(this);

    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapterCustomDrawer);

    //Listener para clique nos itens pai e filho
    mDrawerList.setOnGroupClickListener(this);
    mDrawerList.setOnChildClickListener(this);

...

// Clique em um item filho
@Override
public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
        int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

    // Verifica qual pai foi clicado
    switch (groupPosition) {
    case 1:

        // De acordo com o pai clicado, verifica qual o filho clicado
        switch (childPosition) {

            case 0:
                // Seus métodos         
                break;

            ...

            default:
                break;
        }
    break;

    case 2:

        switch (childPosition) {

            // De acordo com o pai clicado, verifica qual o filho clicado
            case 0:
                // Seus métodos
                break;

            ...

            default:
                break;
        }
    break;

    ...

    default:
        break;
    }

    return false;
}


// Clique em um item pai
@Override
public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
        int groupPosition, long id) {

    switch (groupPosition) {

    case 0:
                // Seus métodos
        break;

    case 1:
                // Seus métodos
        break;

    ...

    default:
        break;
    }

    return false;
}
}
```