# Como adicionar uma ExpandableListView no menu Navigation Drawer do Android

Tags: java, android, lista, navigation-drawer

Criei esse Navigation Drawer que já vem no próprio Android Studio:

[image: Esse aqui]

Porém, queria saber como eu posso transformar essa lista dele expansível. Quero por subitens para cada item da lista.

Já vi esse post: [Menu Navigation Drawer com ExpandableListView](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21734/menu-navigation-drawer-com-expandablelistview)  mas ele cria outro navigation drawer do 0.